# [UIImage retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

We created  button in the init method and we created two Uiimage objects and created Boolean

```
      if(!isHint)
      {
          [hintBtn setImage:hintBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      }
      else
      {
          [hintBtn setImage:hintBtnImagex forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
      }   
      hintBtn =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(794, 144, hintBtnImage.size.width, hintBtnImage.size.height)]; 
      [hintBtn setImage:hintBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [hintBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(showHint) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

When ever user taps the tableview cell we changes the boolean variable and we set the image .like the below code

```
    if(wrongx==1)
    {
        NSLog(@"the wrong x is %i",wrongx);    
        isHint = NO;
        [hintBtn setImage:hintBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

But when i tap the application first time it is working but second time i am getting the below error

```
[UIImage retain]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

Plz reply to my post.Thanks in advance

Comment: did u find the solution for ur question.

Answer (score 0):

where you allocated "hintBtnImage" object.I think your trying to access the "hintBtnImage" withoout allocating.

```
hintBtn =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(794, 144, hintBtnImage.size.width, hintBtnImage.size.height)];
```

small code modification needed ,its not related to solve your problem,above line should be like this

```
hintBtn =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(794, 144, hintBtnImage.size.width, hintBtnImage.size.height)];
      if(!isHint)
      {
          [hintBtn setImage:hintBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      }
      else
      {
          [hintBtn setImage:hintBtnImagex forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
      }
```

Comment: i written the hintBtn allocation in init Method and i allocated before attaching the image still i am getting the error.help me on this.Thanks

Comment: hintBtnImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"hint.png"]; 
      
hintBtnImagex=[UIImage imageNamed:@"hintx.png"]; 
          
  
      hintBtn =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(372, 48, hintBtnImage.size.width-10, hintBtnImage.size.height-10)];
      
      if(!isHint)
      {
          
      [hintBtn setImage:hintBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      }
      else
      {
      [hintBtn setImage:hintBtnImagex forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
      }
      [hintBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(showHint) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: hintBtnImage is autorealese object thats way it is getting released.  use like this hintBtnImage=[[UIImage imageNamed:@"hint.png"]retain];hintBtnImagex=[[UIImage imageNamed:@"hintx.png"]reatain];..make sure to release hintBtnImagex,hintBtnImage in the dealloc.

Comment: you can use another way also.make propery and synthesize for your two images and use like this  self.hintBtnImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"hint.png"]; and self.hintBtnImagex=[UIImage imageNamed:@"hintx.png"];. Finally release in the dealloc method.